# Exec function won't work in Python with a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, exec

I have an initial dataframe called `source_data`.

I have a separate text file which allows a user to place some python code in for some filter criteria. I know this is seen as bad practice, but my company has assured me that it's safe to do. I've noted my concerns but I have the green light.

So, this CSV has this string in a cell: `source_data.loc[source_data['CONFIG_ID'] == 3]`

This is read in as a list. As an example, here's two prints:

```
print('Number of where clause conditions found: ' + str(len(segmentFilterCriteria)))
print('Where clause criteria: ' + str(segmentFilterCriteria))
```

Console shows:

```
Number of where clause conditions found: 1
Where clause criteria: ["source_data.loc[source_data['CONFIG_ID'] == 3]"]
```

Now, when I run this (i.e. using the text string and the exec function), my `base_data` dataframe appears as NoneType:

```
print(segmentFilterCriteria[0])
base_data = exec(segmentFilterCriteria[0])
print(base_data.columns)
```

Console shows:

```
source_data.loc[source_data['CONFIG_ID'] == 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-95-17bc7d85852e>", line 3, in <module>
    print(base_data.columns)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

However, when I just type the code out, like this, it works fine:

```
base_data = source_data.loc[source_data['CONFIG_ID'] == 3]
print(base_data.columns)
```

Console shows:

```
Index(['CONFIG_ID', 'ACCOUNT_DEAL_ID', 'FACILITY_ID',
       'M12_PD_INITIAL_RECOG_VAL',
...
```

Why does my string executed inside an `exec` function not work in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

exec() function doesn't return any result. It always returns None.
You should use it like this:

```
print(segmentFilterCriteria[0])
exec('base_data=' + segmentFilterCriteria[0])
print(base_data.columns)
```